# Ng2-select not working with Angular 6

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, angular6, ng2-bootstrap

Wee upgradedd our front end from angular 2 to Angular 6, everything is smooth but ng2-select component is not working on IE but works in chrome. There is no error but while drop down on UI shows greyed and doesn't populate any data wherein data has been received from the service . Binding is not happening. Anyone faced similar issue? Any resolution of pointer to solve it ?